# How to stream SQL results to JSON using Groovy StreamingJsonBuilder?

Tags: sql, groovy, streaming

I am trying to execute a SQL query and convert the results to JSON as follows. Though I got it working without streaming, I'm having some issues using `StreamingJsonBuilder` to stream the results.

**non-streaming code**

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def jsonBuilder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)
sql.eachRow("select * from client"){ row -> 
    jsonBuilder( id: row.id, name: row.name )
}
println writer.toString()
```

**Result from the code above**

```
{"id":123,"name":"ABCD"}{"id":124,"name":"NYU"}
```

The problem with this result is that, all documents are printed on same line without delimitation. How do I get the results as an array and each document pretty-printed as below

**Expected result**

```
[
   {
      id: 123,
      name: "ABCD",
      ...
   }, 
   {
      id: 124,
      name: "NYU",
      ...
   }, 
]
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines#Always_return_JSON_with_an_Object_on_the_outside

Comment: @cfrick, adding some clarification to provided link is always a good idea.

Comment: @cfrick, The reason I'm looking for an array of JSON objects is because, I'm trying to export relational data and prepare a JSON file so that it can easily be imported to NoSQL databases. So, security is not a concern here for me. Thanks anyway for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put this here more as an fallback.  If your problem is just to have your data properly formatted as json, but the sheer amount of data make you use the streaming API, then you are better off with using the streaming for your data and handle the "array" for yourself.

All the calls in the StreamingJsonBuilder take an object and directly write it to the writer.  So there is no safe way (I can see) to have the writer open the array, then send the data in chunks you provide and then close the array.  So while we already hold the writer, why not just deal with the array your self (this part of json is rather easy to get right):

```
new File('/tmp/out.json').withWriter{ writer ->
    writer << '['
    def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)
    def first = true
    10000000.times{
        if (!first) writer << "\n,"
        first = false
        jsonBuilder(id: it, name: it.toString())
    }
    writer << ']'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've no access to any SQL to try but the following piece of code should do the job (You need to replace the *data* variable):

```
import groovy.json.*

def writer = new StringWriter()
def jsonBuilder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)
def data = [
   [id:1, name: 'n1', other: 'o1'],
   [id:2, name: 'n2', other: 'o2']
]
def dataJson = jsonBuilder(data.collect { [id:it.id, name:it.name] })

println(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(dataJson)))
```

**UPDATE** (after @cfrick's comment)

Here, every row is processed one ofter another but, a *key* (*data* in this case) is needed.

```
import groovy.json.*

def writer = new StringWriter()
def jsonBuilder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(writer)
def data = [
   [id:1, name: 'n1', other: 'o1'],
   [id:2, name: 'n2', other: 'o2']
]
def root = jsonBuilder(data: [])
data.each { d ->
    root.data << [id:d.id, name: d.name]
}

println(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(root)))
```

Comment: but doesn't that actually defeat the purpose of the streaming builder if you collect the whole thing first?

Comment: Probably it does not, however I've no other idea how to get plain list from `JsonBuilder` without specifying the key. Feel free to edit the question if You know how it can be done.

Comment: The prettyPrint works provided the entire collection is kept in memory. However, the `StreamingJsonBuilder` is not streaming anything to the `writer`. Considering the size of the data, I could give up on pretty printing, but not on streaming.

Comment: Is not streaming to the `writer`? With which solution? With the first one all content should be written at once. In the second every single record should be written directly to the `writer`.

Comment: I took the second solution as it is and add `println writer.toString()`. It just prints `{"data":[]}`

Comment: Ok, so as far as I see it won't work. You may use streaming but the whole collection must be processed at once (collect instead of each) as in the first solution.